# How to write the directory in entry as text after selecting the files in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a button that can import many files at the same time and then write the directory of these files into an entry.

An example of this can be found here [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo2lT.png).
However, after importing many files, the directories on the entry appeared with some numbers and words at the beganning and at the end of entry

for example: the correct directory that must appear in the entry is:

C:\Users\Mahmoud Khadijeh\Documents\weight_over_time.png

The one that I got is:
{<_io.TextIWrapper name='C:\Users\Mahmoud Khadijeh\Documents\weight_over_time.png' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>}

In addition, the entry is disabled and its location changed like the image:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkDjq.png)

Any help to solve this problem!

Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x450")
root.title("FTIR Application")



#Open File dialog
frame_Open = LabelFrame(root, text="Import Data", font=('Arial', 8, 'bold'), padx=80, pady=1)
frame_Open.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)



e = Entry(frame_Open, width=50, borderwidth=3)

e.grid(row=0, column=0)


My_Label = Label(frame_Open, text="filename: ")
My_Label.grid(row=0, column=0)
My_Label.place(x=-60, y=00)

def open():
    
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfiles(initialdir="c:/", title="Selecte a file", 
    filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"),("All files","*.*")))
    Name_dir=Label(e, text=root.filename)
    Name_dir.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
    

Browses = Button(frame_Open, text="Browses", highlightthickness = 1, bd=3, command=open)
Browses.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=0)
Browses.place(x=320, y=-5)
```

Comment: `askopenfiles()` return the open file objects, not the filenames.  Use `askopenfilenames()` instead.

Comment: @acw1668
Thank you so much.. Problem Solved after using your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome,

1. I use `from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename` instead of `from tkinter import filedialog`.
2. Instead of creating a new label in the open function which overwrites the entry, the path is now pasted in the entry

hope that helps you.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def open():
    root.filename = askopenfilename(title='Select File')
    e.delete(0, "end")
    e.insert(0, root.filename) # insert path

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x450")
root.title("FTIR Application")

#Open File dialog
frame_Open = LabelFrame(root, text="Import Data", font=('Arial', 8, 'bold'), padx=80, pady=1)
frame_Open.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)

e = Entry(frame_Open, width=50, borderwidth=3)
e.grid(row=0, column=0)

My_Label = Label(frame_Open, text="filename: ")
My_Label.grid(row=0, column=0)
My_Label.place(x=-60, y=00)

Browses = Button(frame_Open, text="Browses", highlightthickness = 1, bd=3, command=open)
Browses.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=0)
Browses.place(x=320, y=-5)

root.mainloop()
```